# Terms (bank,latency) in main memory?

Tags: memory, latency

A CPU has a cache with block size 64 bytes. The main memory has k banks, each  bank being c bytes wide. Consecutive c - byte chunks are mapped on consecutive banks with wrap-around. All the k banks can be accessed in parallel, but two accesses to the same bank must be serialized. A cache block access may involve multiple iterations of parallel bank accesses depending on the amount of data obtained by accessing all the k banks in parallel. Each iteration requires decoding the bank numbers to be accessed in parallel and this takes k/2 ns . The latency of one bank access is 80 ns. If c = 2 and k = 24, the latency of retrieving a cache block starting at address zero from main memory is?

I am not very well known with bank and latency terms in main memory.Can anyone help me to  get information about these terms or provide me a good source from where i can get these all things in good way.

Answer (score 1):

At the risk of sounding lame, all you need is a dictionary, even a non-technical one will do. For example, the [wiktionary.org entry for latency](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/latency) explains that it is a delay. Memory latency is the delay after which the data you read arrives and is valid. It can be measured in clock cycles or actual time, as in your example. It seems to me that your text uses this term to denote what some might call the cache (miss) latency, the delay incurred by not having data in the cache already.

A memory bank is simply a (physical) area of memory. As your text explains, the significance of a main memory bank is that it does not allow concurrent access, and that the logical layout (as seen in memory addresses) is chosen in a way to help parallelize memory access by spreading consecutive locations across different banks.

In your example, the first 2k = 48 bytes of the 80 byte "cache block" are spread across all k=24 banks of memory, and the remaining 32 bytes require accessing 16 banks again in a second iteration. Hence it takes 80 ns + 12 ns + 80 ns + 8 ns to fetch these 80 bytes from main memory.

Answer (score 0):

> Here Time Required will be the time required for *two
>    Parallel Accesses*   as single parallel access will give you only 48 Bytes .For the remaining Bytes you will have to make 1 more parallel access.
>   
>   As per your question

**Time for 1 Parallel Access is = latency + k/2**

Latency is given as 80 ns and k is given as 24

So TIme for 1 Parallel Access is 80+24/2 = 92 ns

And we need to make 2 Access. So 92*2 = 184 ns is the total time required.